# Ribbon designer for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, ribbon

I am trying to create a C# WPF application with a ribbon UI in Visual Studio 2013. I successfully managed to create a project with a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon and could also add "the" ribbon to my UI, by manually editing the XML.

However, I haven't found a UI editor similar to the one for non-ribbon applications provided with Visual Studio. The [Ribbon Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386089.aspx) seems to be available only for Office-based applications.

Is there a visual ribbon editor for Visual Studio 2013 that integrates well with the development environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use application.xaml window to move things around for ribbon related stuff. Its not the same as Office Projects Ribbon Design window operates. I'd stick for XAML code and then see the results afterwards. If you start learning Ribbon for WPF this way from the beginning, you will be able to do more things than using visual editor for Ribbon.

Comment: not the answer I'd hoped for, but still useful, thanks!